# How to add an image file to a table cell, where both these elements are created dynamically using JS?

Tags: javascript

As explained from the title of this problem, I'm trying to create an image in my javaScript code, and after that, I want to add this image into a dynamic table that has a variable number of lines.

Creating the image and adding the cells dynamically isn't a problem, but when I try to assign the img src to a variable that contains the path of this image, the image doesn't load. However, when I put img src="the path as a string", I got no problems. So in sum, I want to find a solution that can allow me to put a variable into the img src, and that being said, the image isn't declared in the HTML code, so I can't use `document.getElementById('myImage').src = myVariable`

**My javaScript code:**

```
function Add_Line(tableID,nom,imageLink)
{
    var ligne = tableID.insertRow(-1);

    var colonne0 = ligne.insertCell(0);
    colonne0.innerHTML += nom;
    //adding the variable nom to the first column(no problem here)

    //trying to insert the string stored into my imageLink variable to the img 
    //src (here is the problem)     
    var colonne2 = ligne.insertCell(2);
    colonne2.innerHTML ='<td align="center"><img src=imageLink></td>'; 
}
```

I expect to have a table that shows a list of items, with each line having its own image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the way you are setting the img src. You are setting it to `<img src=imageLink>`. What you want to do is use the `imageLink` variable:

```
colonne2.innerHTML ='<td align="center"><img src=' + imageLink + '></td>';
```

or using template literals:

```
colonne2.innerHTML =`<td align="center"><img src=${imageLink}></td>`;
```

But keep in mind that this might not be the most secure way to do it, as you are opening up your web page to injection attacks if the `imageLink` variable is arbitrary and is not sanitized in some way.

Comment: Thanks, brother! Spared me a lot of time ^^! I'll keep on mind your advice.